# Is there a way to catch up repeating tasks in Org-Mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use repeating tasks in the org-mode agenda for, for example, a daily checklist of things that need to be done.  But if I go on vacation, for example, then all the dates are out of date, in which case I have to either mark them each done over and over in the agenda view, or else manually edit the dates in the actual .org file.  Is there a "catch up" function that I just don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you use the ++1d or .+1d repeater, you'll just have to ack them once. While, by default, with the +1d repeater, you'll see them all 15x times...

Comment: But you have to mark an item DONE to "catch up" with it, even though you haven't done it. Also, what about the bunch of old items in the .org files which all use the regular `+1d` repeaters?

Comment: True, but I see no other obvious solution, except if you reschedule them after your vacantion, for example. You can do that in "bulk" mode (all marked tasks at once), using the B prefix (`B s` to Schedule, IIRC).

Comment: OK, that's fine, you can also mark the instance of the overdue item as Cancelled and have it reappear as a new instance with the `++` or `.+` repeater.  On another note, could you please help me set up a single key (e.g. redefine the `r` key) command in the agenda to re-schedule a task at +3 days from today? Or does this deserve a separate question? Thanks!

Comment: I think it's preferrable to make a new question for that, yes. Ping me, if necessary.